# How can a 'WHERE column LIKE "%expression%" ' perform better than a MATCH(column) AGAINST("expression") in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search

I've run into a serious MySQL performance bottleneck which I'm unable to understand and resolve. Here are the table structures, indexes and record counts (bear with me, it's only two tables):

```
mysql> desc elggobjects_entity;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| guid        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title       | text                | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| description | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from elggobjects_entity;
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| elggobjects_entity |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | guid        | A         |      613637 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| elggobjects_entity |          1 | title    |            1 | title       | NULL      |         131 |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |
| elggobjects_entity |          1 | title    |            2 | description | NULL      |         131 |     NULL | NULL   |      | FULLTEXT   |         |
+--------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from elggobjects_entity;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   613637 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc elggentity_relationships;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| guid_one     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| relationship | varchar(50)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| guid_two     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| time_created | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> show index from elggentity_relationships;
+--------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                    | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| elggentity_relationships |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id           | A         |    11408236 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| elggentity_relationships |          0 | guid_one     |            1 | guid_one     | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| elggentity_relationships |          0 | guid_one     |            2 | relationship | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| elggentity_relationships |          0 | guid_one     |            3 | guid_two     | A         |    11408236 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| elggentity_relationships |          1 | relationship |            1 | relationship | A         |    11408236 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| elggentity_relationships |          1 | guid_two     |            1 | guid_two     | A         |    11408236 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from elggentity_relationships;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 11408236 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I'd like to use an INNER JOIN on those two tables and perform a full text search.

Query:

```
SELECT
        count(DISTINCT o.guid) as total
FROM
        elggobjects_entity o
INNER JOIN
        elggentity_relationships r on (r.relationship="image" AND r.guid_one = o.guid)
WHERE
        ((MATCH (o.title, o.description) AGAINST ('scelerisque' )))
```

This gave me a 6 minute (!) response time.

On the other hand this one

```
SELECT
        count(DISTINCT o.guid) as total
FROM
        elggobjects_entity o
INNER JOIN
        elggentity_relationships r on (r.relationship="image" AND r.guid_one = o.guid)
WHERE
        ((o.title like "%scelerisque%") OR (o.description like "%scelerisque%"))
```

returned the same count value in 0.02 seconds.

How is that possible? What am I missing here? 
(MySQL info: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1)

**EDIT**

EXPLAINing the first query (using match .. against) gives:

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type     | possible_keys         | key          | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref      | guid_one,relationship | relationship | 152     | const | 6145 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | fulltext | PRIMARY,title         | title        | 0       |       |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

while the second query (using LIKE "%..%"):

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys         | key          | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | guid_one,relationship | relationship | 152     | const               | 6145 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY      | 8       | elgg1710.r.guid_one |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried "EXPLAIN"ing each query?

Comment: @James Anderson added EXPLAIN outputs to question.

Comment: Have you run multiple tests to try to eliminate the effects of caching of data?

Comment: @Tim Yes, several times. Results were roughly the same, LIKE clauses always gave 0.01 - 0.03 response times, while the MATCH .. AGAINST clasue returned after several minutes (in between 4 and 7). I must be overlooking something obvious, these results are simply impossible.

Comment: does expanding the match into 2 separate statements speed it up? `(MATCH (o.title) AGAINST ('scelerisque' )) OR (MATCH (o.description) AGAINST ('scelerisque'))`

Comment: Can you test how long it takes to run this query: `SELECT
    count(DISTINCT o.guid) as total
FROM
    ( select * from elggobjects_entity where (MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('scelerisque' )) ) o
INNER JOIN
    elggentity_relationships r on (r.relationship="image" AND r.guid_one = o.guid)`

Comment: @gnur Using only one column (o.title) for the match gives the following error message: ERROR 1191 (HY000): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list. The fulltext index was defined for multiple (title, desciption) columns, I guess it can't be used on a single column. (?)

Comment: @Karolis: 21.59s, also tested with 3 other expression to match against, average is about 30s. Which is better than I got before (why?) but still very bad (why?, again)

Comment: @András, OK, interesting. It would be good to get an EXPLAIN output of my query.

Comment: @Karolis: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/7098/20110705-3jao-51kb.jpg

Comment: @Everyone I've uploaded a gzipped dump of these two tables, available here: http://sandbox.wamped.org/db_performance_issue.sql.gz (watch out, size is 66M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining your experience and EXPLAIN's results, it seems that fulltext index is not as useful as you expect in this particular case. This depends on particular data in your database, on database structure or/and particular query.

Usually database engines use no more than one index per table. So when the table has more than one index, query optimizer tries to use the better one. But optimizer is not always clever enough.

EXPLAIN's output shows that database query optimizer decided to use indexes for `relationship` and `title`. The relationship filter reduces table `elggentity_relationships` to 6145 rows. And the title filter reduces the table `elggobjects_entity` to 72697 rows. Then MySQL needs to join those tables (6145 x 72697 = 446723065 filtering operations) without using any index because indexes have already been used for filtering. In this case this can be too much. MySQL can even make a decision to keep intermediate calculations in the hard drive by trying to keep enough free space in memory.

Now let's take a look into another query. It uses `relationship` and `PRIMARY KEY` (of table elggobjects_entity) as its indexes. The relationship filter reduces table `elggentity_relationships` to 6145 rows. By joining those tables on `PRIMARY KEY` index, the result gets only 3957 rows. This is not much for the last filter (i.e. `LIKE "%scelerisque%"`), even if index is NOT used for this purpose at all.

As you can see the speed much depends on indexes selected for a query. So, in this particular case the `PRIMARY KEY` index is much more useful than fulltext `title` index, because `PRIMARY KEY` has bigger impact for result reduction than `title`.

MySQL is not always clever to set the right indexes. We can do this manually, by using clauses like `IGNORE INDEX (index_name)`, `FORCE INDEX (index_name)`, etc.

But in your case the problem is that if we use `MATCH() AGAINST()` in a query then the fulltext index is required, because `MATCH() AGAINST()` doesn't work without fulltext index at all. So this is the main reason why MySQL has chosen incorrect indexes for the query.

**UPDATE**

OK, I did some investigation.

Firstly, you may try to force MySQL to use `guid_one` index instead of `relationship` on table `elggentity_relationships`: `USE INDEX (guid_one)`.

But for even better performance I think you can try to create one index for the composition of two columns (`guid_one`, `membership`). Current index `guid_one` is very similar, but for 3 columns, not for 2. In this query there are only 2 columns used. In my opinion after index creation MySQL should automatically use the right index. If not, force MySQL to use it.

*Note: After index creation don't forget to remove old `USE INDEX` instruction from your query, because this may prevent query from using the newly created index. :)*

Comment: thanks for digging into this! So are you telling me that MySQL tries to do a match .. against() on the whole elggobjects_entity table, and not on the set of rows filtered by the INNER JOIN clause? If so, is there any way to tell MySQL in what order the join and where clauses should be executed? Like with STRAIGHT_JOINS I could specify the join order, but that won't work in this case.

Comment: @András, yes, MySQL tries to do match...against() on the whole elggobjects_entity table. But this is not the problem. This is fast because of index. The problem is that this table used one index for match...against(), so this table can't use another index for joining operation. So this means that table joining operation is done without any index.

Comment: ok, now I get it. Does this mean that there is no way to refactor the above query (using match ... against) to reach reasonable performance? Is really sticking to the plain old LIKE "%..%" is my only solution here?

Comment: About the same as I can reach with the LIKE "%..%" clause. Couple hundred milliseconds. This query is called by a search page which will be used frequently by multiple users. Can't have a web interface hanging for minutes.